# How to put 2 rows returned from a query into into 2 columns of a single row in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I run a query that returns 2 rows

```
SELECT a FROM TABLE-A WHERE condition=something;
```

> row1    Value1
>
> row2    Value2

Now, I want to put it in a new table in 2 columns of a single row

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM TABLE-B WHERE condition=something;
```

> row1   column1   column2
>
> ```
>    value1   value2
> ```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: think you are looking for pivot. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how you want to pick which row goes into which column - here are a couple of options:

```
SELECT MIN( a ) AS minimum_value,
       MAX( a ) AS maximum_value
FROM   table_a
WHERE  1=1;
```

or

```
SELECT MAX( a ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS first_value,
       MAX( a ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS last_value
FROM   table_a
WHERE  1=1;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT a, ROWNUM AS rn FROM table_a WHERE 1=1 )
PIVOT  ( MAX(a) FOR rn IN ( 1 AS first_value, 2 AS second_value ) );
```